# Meaning of confidence interval refered to standard deviation

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, bioinformatics

I was reading a proteomic paper few days ago and I got confused on one aspect.
In the paper is written:

"The global mean and S.D. of protein ratios (47-1/D3) were calculated for each replicate. The cutoff points for protein differential expression were mean +/-
2 S.D.(95% confidence interval)".

I do not understand the meaning of the 95% confidence interval in the sentence.
Basically, they have ratio of protein expression and they have to set a threshold to define from which value on the protein can be considered significantly regulated. This limit, described in the sentence, is quite unclear from me from the statistical point of view.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I understood the meaning here. Since they consider the mean +/- 2 SD they are covering 95% of the variability of the distribution. This is what they refer to as confidence iterval. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what they do in the paper, but it rather looks like a *prediction interval* (because for a confidence interval around the mean it should be $\pm 2sd/\sqrt{n}$).

Answer (score 1):

You're basically correct, Confidence Interval (CI) is a way of defining what a given +/- interval describes in terms of how much of the variability distribution it covers.

As used in that quote, ±2 S.D. is basically redundant with 95% CI*.  The way they're using the term seems unusual to me, since [Confidence Interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) is conventionally used for population parameters (like stating the results of an opinion survey, or medical study), but mathematically I don't think it's wrong to state it that way.

*Not actually redundant, **2 SD** is a **95.45%** CI, the most common approximation of **95%** CI is **[1.96](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96)**.